# How to do downgrading cuda version

Tags: cuda

I'm currently using the cuda version 4.2 but I need to change it to 3.1. Is it possible to uninstall the current version (ver 4.2) and then install the previous version (ver 3.1) ?

EDIT : Please refer that my os system is linux ubuntu 10.04 64bit.

EDIT : I found how to get the version of 3.1. I have to send e-mail to "devzoneupdate@nvidia.com" to request this old version. Now, please let me know how to uninstall 4.2 then install 3.1.

EDIT : I downloaded cuda 3.1 by request to nvidia, then installed toolkit and SDK. When install the cuda 3.1 toolkit there comes the question about uninstallation of current version. For SDK, we can just delete ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK directory directly for the uninstallation of it. After deleting I could install the cuda 3.1 SDK. I'm done, thanks all.

Comment: Are you talking about the development tool or the nVidia graphic driver that includes cuda?

Comment: I mean the development environment, such as toolkit/driver/SDK. It is because I'm setting one gpu simulator up on my linux system, but this simulator does not support 4.x and higher version. It says the version of 3.1 is highly recommended.

Comment: You can download older toolkits from the [archive page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive).  You can find additional instructions in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595167/cross-compile-to-older-cuda-toolkit-version/13595329#13595329).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily downgrade the CUDA version provided you aren't using the CUDA toolkit functions which are only present in version greater than 3.1.

Also you would have to modify your project settings to use CUDA Rules version 3.1.

Comment: Could you let me know how can do it? I can not find the way to uninstall and install.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux Ubuntu 10.04. BTW, I'm trying to download cuda 3.1 toolkit/driver/SDK, but could not find yet.

Comment: sorry but i work on windows.

yeah i think nvidia has discontinued archiving the old releases.
you may get it through torrent links or sharing websites.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING:

ubuntu 12.04 upgraded to 12.10 with standard cuda 4.2 installed; in the process of downgrading to CUDA 4.0 using NVIDA installer resulted the !! COMPLETE REMOVAL !! /usr/bin/

probably is a good idea to choose "NO" when removing existing CUDA installation is offered; though I never got to try it as only already loaded firefox remained functional.